# Ajax: не приходит ответ

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Здравствуйте!

Для обновления информации на сайте использую аякс, при этом код php файла-обработчика на сервере выполняется, всё срабатывает без ошибок. Но не приходит ответ на исходную страничку. Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NNN = 0;
    var req = 0;

    function scheme(number) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); //new обязательно -иначе в ие и хроме не пашет

        if (req) {
            req.open("POST", 'http://www.site.com/admin/modules/scheme.php?scheme=' + number, true); //скрипт к которому обращаемся
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // заголовок в посте это обязательный атрибут
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange_scheme; // обработчик приёма ответа
            req.send('gfgdf=fdfsd'); // значения
        }
    }

    function processReqChange_scheme() {
        //var statusElem = document.getElementById('scheme1')
        try {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                alert(req.responseText);
                // для статуса "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    statusElem.innerHTML = req.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("Ne udalos poluchit dannie:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    }
</script>
```

Т.е. выдает результат: не удалось получить данные req.status равен 0, хотя обработчик отлично срабатывает.

Comment: Ничего не пойму - при этом при всем firebug пишет: Ответ 200 ОК.

Comment: а какой точный ответ в firebug от сервера приходит?

Comment: 200 OK
И всё.

Comment: кхм....а php файл лежит в том же домене?

Comment: JS-код работает. Ищите ошибку в серверной части. Либо действительно посылаете запрос не к тому же домену, с которого посылаете запрос - а это запрещено политикой безопасности браузеров.

Comment: @Равнодушный хочешь сказать что я не могу с домена vasya.ru отправить запрос AJAX'ом на домен petya.ru? Браузер мне скажет что я неправ?

Я что-то не знаю в этой жизни? Как же ради бога, объяснить работу счетчика Я.Метрики и прочих, они с ошибками отправляют данные?

А как же API множества сайтов, которые предоставляют к ним доступ?

Comment: @Shrek, да, не можешь. Да, скажет, что ты не прав. Да, ты многое в этой жизни не знаешь. Что касается метрики и прочего апи - чаще всего скрипты с сайта-1 подключаются в сайт-2, так что доменом этих скриптов остается сайт-1 и может отправлять любые запросы к себе; в иных случаях, используются более извращенные методы, но все это называется "кросс-доменный скриптинг".